# How to learn game development when i understand the concepts but don`t know how to implement?

Tags: architecture

I have a basic level of programming knowledge, gained trough high-school classes and personal interest and also understand certain game design patterns like game loops, collision detection etc.

My problem is, i don`t understand how to get started with making games without falling in a gap, between tutorials that just cover the basics, that i already know and understand and tutorials that are to complicated for me.

For example, today i got a little gameloop and implemented a graphical output. Than, when i tried to implement a buffer i failed, because i simply didn`t understood where to put it in my existing system.

What would you recommend someone in my situation ? Should i start from zero or are there other certain techniques for learning ?

Comment: _"without falling in a gap"_ When you learned to walk, you've certainly fell a bunch of times, you hurt yourself and you cried. Everyone does. And every programmer, at one point in their programming career, programmed themselves in a corner and had to redo big chunks of work. I despise the code I wrote 5 years ago because I always evolve. All of this to say: just do it, you won't remember your baby steps 5 years from now. You _will_ make mistakes, but you'll learn a lot.

Comment: Your question is off topic, though (please read the [help]). If you have precise questions on a precise topic, where a precise answer exist, please do come back and ask, that what's this Q&A site is for :)

Comment: You can always look for tutorials that cover a wider range, like [Handmade Hero](https://www.youtube.com/user/handmadeheroarchive), which goes from effectively zero to a full and complete game.